# laravel make view without blade for solid message

Tags: php, laravel, view

I want to do a function that returns a view, but if the item you're looking for isn't found, just return a hidden message in the view object.

```
public function getBannerById(string $banner_id): View
   $banner = Banner::find($banner_id);

   if (!$banner) {
      return view()->append('<!-- Banner not found! -->'); // this not work
   }

  // more code ....

  return view('banner', ['banner' => $banner]);
}
```

Comment: Clarify *hidden message in the view object*, also describe what you've tried so far so we can gain a better understanding as to what you're trying to accomplish and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Why not just load a view with the "hidden message"? And why without blade?

Comment: a function that only returns a banner?  perhaps if you explained the business problem

Comment: Can you give us the update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel Session for this, if the items isn't found so return to your view with the session message and then in the view you verify if exists the session and display the message.

In controller:

```
   if (!$banner) {
       Session::flash('error', "Banner not found!");
      return view('view.name'); // 
   }
```

In View

```
@if (session('error'))
     <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
         {{ session('error') }}
     </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Flash is not really a hidden message ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return `Banner not found` OR attach if-else statements in your blade file as below:

**Controller code:**

```
<?php

public function getBannerById(string $banner_id): View
   $banner = Banner::find($banner_id);
   return view('banner', compact('banner'));
}
```

**View blade file:**

```
@if(!$banner)
  <p> Banner not found!</p>
@else
  // Your view you wish to display
@endif
```

**Update:**

You can also use [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions) method to automatically send 404 response back to the client if the banner is not found.

```
$banner = Banner::findOrFail($banner_id);
```